# It seems like my function is only receiving the first char of a string when being called

Tags: mysql, c, authentication, variables, pass-by-reference

I am building a basic registration feature for a school project and keep getting an error when I try to check the username and password from a database. The idea is to have a user type in their login info and then have a function receive that information and compare it with the user info from the database. if it matches it will retrieve the user id from the table and attach it to a variable for later use. I am having an issue now where it seems like when I pass in the user input into the password match function, the function only receives the first char of the input. That's what the debugger shows. I may be reading the debugger wrong but I am not sure here is the first function

```
void loginUser(){
    
    char email[100];
    char password[50];

    // Input login details
    printf("Enter email: ");
    fgets(email, sizeof(email), stdin);
    email[strcspn(email, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove newline character
    printf("Enter password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove newline character
        
    printf("Email: %s\n", email);

    printf("Email: %s\n", password);

    // Check email and password against database
    if(password_match(email, password)){
        printf("Success");
    };

    // If authenticated, proceed to main menu
    // Else, show error message and redirect to login
};
```

and this is the function that gets the username and password from mysql database

```
int password_match(const char *email, const char *password) {

//    printf("Email: %s\n", email);

//     printf("Email: %s\n", password);

    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char query[512];
    snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT consumerID FROM CurrentConsumer WHERE email='%s' AND password='%s'", email, password);
    
    if (mysql_query(con, query)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error querying database: %s\n", mysql_error(con));
        return 0; // Failure
    }
    
    result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error storing result: %s\n", mysql_error(con));
        return 0; // Failure
    }
    
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    if (row == NULL) {
        mysql_free_result(result);
        return 0; // No match
    }
    
    // Print the consumer ID
    printf("Consumer ID: %s\n", row[0]);
    
    mysql_free_result(result);
    return 1; // Match
}
```

I tried using both pass by value and pass by reference but cant get it to work. It's weird because I have another function that inserts data into the database just fine. I used that to build this function but cant get it to work.

Comment: What do the commented-out `printf` lines in your `password_match` function show, when you un-comment them? That will/should show what arguments the function is receiving.

Comment: I don't have a platform on which I can test your MySQL calls, but the logic of your code and function call looks OK and printing out the passed arguments and the `query` value written show the correct/expected values when I test it.

Comment: Your printing claims to print the email address twice, but actually prints the password on the second call.  However, I don't think that's your main problem.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  However, fixing that can wait for a little while.

Comment: You don't show how the connection to the database is established, so we can't see if there is a problem initializing `con`.  There is also a question — to you use `scanf()` before calling the login function?  But printing the parameter information in the password checking function should help a lot.  It will identify whether the problem is in the calling code or the called code.

Comment: You're going to have a fun time when [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) tries to log in.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an issue now where it seems like when I pass in the user input into the password match function, the function only receives the first char of the input.

this is the function prototype:

```
   int password_match(const char* a, const char* b)
```

`password_match()` receives 2 pointers to `char`. No `char` at all. The pointers can point to `NULL`, to valid or invalid `NULL`-terminated things, but are just pointers to some addresses.

The only way for it to receive a single letter string is that `a[0]` is a letter and `a[1]` is zero, or the same for `b`.

#### about the code

- `loginUser()` is just a wrapper around 2 strings in order to test `password_match()`. Do not write interactive code to test your program. It will only cost you time. Much time. Just pass 2 strings to `loginUser` and return the user id
- do not use `void f(void)`: this things will get no data and return nohing so will depend entirely on global external data.
- code to check user and password in a database is not relevant here yet: you just want to test the arguments coming into `password_match()`
- do not mix *snake_case* and *camelCase*. In general in `C` we expect snake_case, but anyway just be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help both with suggestions and editing the post. The issue was that I didn't take time to review and look at the obvious. I forgot to include a function to start the actual database. so the queries had no place to go. I should have just waited and looked at the problem under fresh eyes instead of trying to solve it at 3:30 in the morning. My bad for taking up your time. Next I can worry about sql injection to make sure the system is secure. Thank you all again.